# How to check whether a number is a "NaN" in Java / Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nan

Please have a look at the following code

```
private List createTheDynamicWordList(String algorithm, double averageStat)
    {

        Toast.makeText(context, ""+averageStat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

in some cases, I get the `averageStat` as a 'NaN' value. I need to check whether the number if 'NaN' or not. How can I do this? Using `NumberFormatException` here didn't work.

Comment: How can you possibly get `averageStat` as `NaN`?  Are you sure you're working in Java and not JavaScript?

Comment: @AleksG: Yes. This is a kind of statistic generation from a database. When "Divide By 0" I have to get this. I couldn't track it with exception handling, maybe because it is inside a loop

Answer (score 25, accepted):

in your case should be enough:

```
   if (Double.isNaN(averageState))
```

take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28double%29)

Answer (score 5):

Use static method [Double.isNaN()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28double%29)